# Connect application to OneDrive for Business China

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

We have an application that connects to OneDrive for Business using the Microsoft-graph API. The application is registered in `apps.dev.microsoft.com`.

Now we want to support OneDrive for Business Chinese edition. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/o365-china-endpoints), we changed the endpoints to the Chinese `21Vianet` endpoints. However, when the Office 365 Chinese users try to authorize our application, they get this error:

> AADSTS700016: Application with identifier
>   'xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx was not found in the directory
>   'userdomain.com'. This can happen if the application has not been
>   installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any
>   user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to
>   the wrong tenant.

It seems that the application registration at `apps.dev.microsoft.com` is not working for China. Do I have to register our application somewhere else and get another identifier? I can not find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you referenced is out of date. You should instead be following the [Nation Cloud Deployments](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/deployments) documentation from the Microsoft Graph site.

The problem you're running into is that the v2 App Model (which is what `apps.dev.microsoft.com` generates) and the v2 Endpoint are not supported with National Cloud Deployments:

> **Note**: The Azure AD v2.0 authorization and token endpoints are available on the global service only; they are not yet supported for use with national cloud deployments.

Before you can authenticate users in China, you will need to register a new App ID using the v1 App Model. This is done by registering your application as a multi-tenant app via the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com).

You'll also need to change your authorization workflow to use the v1 Endpoint. For global endpoints, this is `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?{your settings`. For the Chinese endpoint, you want to use `https://login.chinacloudapi.cn/common/oauth2/authorize`.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I followed the steps, however I still can not authorize the application for China. I created a new Tenant and a multi-tenant app using the Azure Portal. I guess that maybe the problem is that the Tenant location is not in China, but when I create a new Tenant there is no option to select China in the list of countries.